# Google Maps Javascript API - bounds.contains method

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I created a map with the Google Maps API (Javascript) as follows:

```
var currentLocation = {lat: 47.3663615, lng: 8.5388539};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: zoomLevel,
    center: currentLocation,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
});
```

I was then trying to use the bound.contain function to check whether various LatLng positions are contained within the map bounds or not:

```
var center = map.getCenter(); // works fine
var bounds = map.getBounds(); // works fine
var x = bounds.contains(center); // works fine, delivers true
var a = bounds.contains(currentLocation); throws an error (Uncaught TypeError: a.lat is not a function)
```

After some debugging, it seems that the currentLocation Object doesn't have the right format to be processed with the method "contains". Please note that I'm quite new to javascript and the Google Maps api.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 8):

`LatLngBounds.contains` currently requires a `LatLng` as argument, a `LatLngBoundsLiteral` will not be accepted.

Use

```
var currentLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(47.3663615,8.5388539);
```

Comment: Corrected as suggested. Works perfectly fine now. Many thanks for the prompt answer and the hint.